# Default URL of Cisco ASA 5505 not displaying login page

Tags: firewall, cisco, asa

We have a Cisco ASA 5505 firewall device and I need to try and do some configuration on it remotely but upon navigating to the suggested URL of https://192.168.1.1/admin nothing is being displayed. Any ideas of how I can find what the IP of the device is so that it can be configured from within a machine on the network

Answer (score 0):

there are 2 solutions here :

1. you must change the browser or make an update for it and also check
   if the java is enabled on the browser.
2. the second solution is to check the Cisco Asa is already configured
   to display the web interface at this step you also need to check if
   your cisco asa have Asdm installed on it and the HTTPSERVER ENABLE
   on the ASA
3. 3.if you don't what to do send me a msg